# Useful helper functions in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, function, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

What are some useful helper functions you all use in Laravel? I currently only have two, but I am interested to read on what type of functions folks have created in the past to spark some inspiration into the future.

I have these two global ones in my app:

```
Blade::extend(function($value) {
   return preg_replace('/\@define(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
});

HTML::macro('raw', function($htmlbuilder) {
   return htmlspecialchars_decode($htmlbuilder);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more Helper function in View

```
 View::share('human_size', function($bytes) {
    $units = ['B', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB'];
    for ($i = 0; $bytes > 1024; $i++) {
        $bytes /= 1024;
    }
    return round($bytes, 2).' '.$units[$i];
});
```

and called in blade like: `{{ $human_size(123456789) }}`

[Some other function that created in the past to spark some inspiration into the future](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions)